# Stored Procedure brings 0 only with ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2005

I'm having a problem with an ASP 2005 application, the problem is that I´m calling a stored procedure in Oracle saved on a package, that procedure is very heavy (has like 1000 lines) and at the end it inserts into a table the data that it just calcutaded, then in other vb function I get the information from that table and show it on a gridview, but the 2 columns that are calculated sometimes come with value 0 and sometimes come with the values that should be. This only happens when I call the precedure from asp, when I run it from Toad it always get values on those columns... Do you have an idea of what could be happening??

This is the function I use for sending parameters:

```
Private Function LoadTable(ByVal tipee As String, ByVal period As String, ByRef ErrorUser As String, ByVal dateInit As String, ByVal dateEnd As String) As Boolean
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "Schema.PKG.procedureA"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim Prmts(6) As OracleClient.OracleParameter
    Prmts(0) = New System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter("ptipotrans", OracleType.VarChar)
    Prmts(0).Value = tipee
    Prmts(1) = New System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter("pperiodo", OracleType.VarChar)
    Prmts(1).Value = period
    Prmts(2) = New System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter("pfechaini", OracleType.VarChar)
    If dateInit = "" Then
        Prmts(2).Value = DBNull.Value
    Else
        Prmts(2).Value = dateInit
    End If
    Prmts(3) = New System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter("pfechafin", OracleType.VarChar)
    If dateEnd = "" Then
        Prmts(3).Value = DBNull.Value
    Else
        Prmts(3).Value = dateEnd
    End If
    Prmts(4) = New System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter("perror", OracleType.VarChar, 100)
    Prmts(4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Prmts(i))
    Next
    Dim cls_sql As New cls_ejecutaSql
    Return cls_sql.exec_ens(cmd, errorUser)
End Function
```

And this the function I use for connecting to Oracle:

```
Public Function exec_ens(ByVal cmd As OracleCommand, ByRef msg As String) As Boolean
    Dim lint_resul As Boolean
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        lint_resul = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        msg = cmd.Parameters("perror").Value
        lint_resul = False
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
    Return lint_resul
End Function
```

I don't see  anything out of the normal in those functions, and I also verified that the parameters are being sent well

Comment: Please provide the function as an example. Are you saying that the PL/SQL is doing all the work? Inserting the data?

Comment: I added the functions, and yes, that procedure makes the calculation and then insert the data, then with another function I get the data inserted and put it on a DataTable and then on a GridView

Comment: Does the data inserted into the table have zeros or are the zeros coming in when you read from the table from ASP?

Comment: just the data in 2 columns is inserted as zero, but only happens when I call from asp, if I run it with the same parameters from Toad it does not insert zeros

Comment: Then it must be the parameters being sent to the function. Add debug code to the ASP function

Comment: I did it, I'm pretty sure that thge parameters are the ones they should be just before of add them to the OracleCommand and also I put a variable that is written at the end of the procedure with the parameter it received and they are thr right ones

Comment: I also try and write a string parameter burned when I assign the value to the OracleCommand and sometimes gives me 0 and other gives me the correct value